# How to selectively bold part of an x-axis label in ggplot like you can do for the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know it's possible to selectively bold part of the legend text in ggplot. For instance, something like this:

`scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF0000", "#0000FF"), labels=c("**label** 1", "label 2"))`

will render "**label 1**, label 2" in the legend, with bolding for label 1. I am wondering if it's possible to do the same thing for specific labels on the x-axis. I would like to bold *parts* of *some* x-axis labels, but not all of them.  If you try to use `scale_x_discrete`, the asterisk trick doesn't work for bolding -- the asterisks just appear in the axis label. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a built-in feature of ggplot2, neither for the legend text nor the axis text or any other element. Instead, this feature is implemented via an extension package and most likely the `ggtext` package. However, as there are packages which use `ggtext` under the hood this might lead to the impression that using markdown syntax, e.g. `**` for bold, is a built-in feature.

This said, you could use this feature using `ggtext::element_markdown()`  in `theme()`, e.g. for the x axis text use `axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown()`.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on mtcars:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = factor(am))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("#FF0000", "#0000FF"),
    labels = c("**label** 1", "label 2")
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = c(100, 200, 300),
    labels = paste(c("**100**", 200, 300), "mpg")
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.text = ggtext::element_markdown(),
    axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this answers my question!

Comment: A follow-up question... before I was using theme(axis.text.x = element_text()) for my plot, and I had a parameter set vjust=7, to move the axis labels closer to the plot.  When I change it to theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown()) I do get bolding with the asterisks like I want, but the vjust=7 appears to not be working anymore -- the x-axis labels won't respond to vjust.  Any idea as to why this could be?

Comment: Interesting. Wasn't aware of this change in behavior. However, best is you forget about using `vjust` this way. v/hjust set the alignment and are not meant to shift or move labels. Instead I would suggest to use margin, e.g. try with `ggtext::element_markdown(margin = margin(t = 0))` to remove the top margin of the axis text. And if you want to add some margin, then you could e.g. do `margin(t = 2, units = "cm")` to add exactly 2cm of margin.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!